# Gap appearing in navigation bar and dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, navigationbar

1. I can't seem to solve the 'gap' that appears below my navigational tabs
2. Also can somebody please help me with a drop down navigation? I need to put 3 subheadings under SHOP, 2 subheadings under DISCOVER and 3 subheadings under EDGE CLUB. I'm too confused with the multiple < li > and < ul > !

This is my first time and thanks in advance ...

```css
.navigation {
 background-color: #454242;
 text-align:center;
}

ul.menu {
 height: 43px;
 background-color: #454242;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: 1.0s;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight:400;
 display:inline-block;
 text-align: center;
}

ul.menu li {
 float: left;
 display: inline;
}

ul.menu li a {
 display: inline-block;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: 1.0s;
 font-size: 17px;
 height: 23px;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 color: black;
}

ul.menu li a:active {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 color: black;
}

ul.menu li.icon {
 display:none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) { 
ul.menu li:not(:first-child){
 display:none;
 margin: auto;
 float: left;
}
 
ul.menu li.icon {
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 text-align: left;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
 
ul.menu.responsive li.icon {
 
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: left;
 color: black;
}
 
ul.menu.responsive{
 position: relative;
 height: 258px;
 transition: 1.0s;
 width: 100%
}
 
ul.menu.responsive li{
 float: none;
 display: inline;
 
}
 
ul.menu.responsive li a{
 display:block;
 text-align: center;
} 
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation col-12">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="icon">
<a href="javascript:void(0);"onClick="dropdownMenu()">&#9776;</a></li>
<li> <a href="test.html">Home</a></li>
<li> <a href="test.html">Eat</a></li>
<li> <a href="test.html">Shop</a></li>
<li> <a href="test.html">Discover</a></li>
<li> <a href="test.html">Edge Club</a></li>
<li> <a href="test.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
function dropdownMenu() {
 document.getElementsByClassName("menu")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline elements automatically have space applied around them. Because `ul-menu` is defined as `inline-block`, it receives this treatment. This space is the gap below the tabs.

To remove the space, change `display` back to `block` and then you can center it using `width` and `margin:auto`.

---

As for subheadings, you will need to nest lists and apply similar styles. [Here's a good example.](https://codepen.io/philhoyt/pen/ujHzd)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `display: inline-flex` for `ul.menu`

Answer (score 0):

(1)
here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/51ueowx7/1/

there was only two updates to the css in order to remove issues caused by whitespace

```
ul.menu{
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}
```

possible dupe: [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

(2)

The first step I would take would be to remove the anchors. Considering you don't want every click to navigate to another page, it would likely be preferential to assign click handlers.

You're already familiar enough with lists to be able to nest them, I believe a little bit of formatting would be significantly helpful in this scenario:

```
<li id="shop">
    <p>Shop</p>
    <ul class="shop-subheadings">
        <li>Subheading 1</li>
        <li>Subheading 2</li>
        <li>Subheading 3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

to start you would likely want:

```
ul.shop-subheadings{
    display: none;
}
```

You may then add/use classes || IDs in order to assign click functionality.

```
$("#shop").click(function(){
    $("ul.shop-subheadings").show();
})
```

Here's a rough start: https://jsfiddle.net/51ueowx7/8/